# Calculate opacity and saturation from color given in signed integer format

Tags: android, colors, opacity

In my android app I have a color pick activity using Lars Werkman ColorPicker View. I'd like to start this activity setting the color picker and the opacity saturation bars to the values of the previously selected color. the color picker is easy but the opacity and saturation bars need some calculation first.

How can i calculate these two values given the signed-integer form of the color?

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.colorToHSV(currentColor, hsv); //hsv for hue, saturation, value
float saturation = hsv[1];
float value = hsv[2];
int opacity = Color.alpha(currentColor);
```